# Converting .h5/.hic file to .csv/.json

Tags: python, json, h5py

I want to convert .h5/.hic files to .csv/.json format. I found this https://pypi.org/project/h5json/ and their GitHub page https://github.com/HDFGroup/hdf5-json to convert to json from h5. I was successful in installing it but I could not move forward after that. I looked into other options too but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is `pandas`, see the [official guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-hdf5).

Here an example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": list(range(5)), "y": list(range(5))})
df.to_hdf("tab.h5", "table")
pd.read_hdf("tab.h5", "table").to_json("tab.json")
```

In my environment, I used https://pypi.org/project/tables/ to correctly install `PyTables`